# Regex on io.Text RDD using scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, filter

I have a problem. I need to extract some data from a file like this:

```
(3269,
<page>
<title>Anarchism</title>
<ns>0</ns>
<id>12</id>
<revision>...
)
(194712,
<page>
<title>AssistiveTechnology</title>
<ns>0</ns>
<id>23</id>.. 
) etc...
```

This file was generated using:

```
val conf = new Configuration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "</page>")
val rdd=sc.newAPIHadoopFile("sample.bz2", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
rdd.map{case (k,v) => (k.get(), new String(v.copyBytes()))}
```

I need to obtain the title content. Im using regex but the output file still remains empty. My code is like this:

```
val xx = rdd.map(x => x._2).filter(x => x.matches(".*<title>([A-Za-z]+)<\\/title>.*"))
```

I also try with these:

```
".*<title>([A-Za-z]+)</title>.*"
```

And using this:

```
val reg = ".*<title>([\\w]+)</title>.*".r
val xx = rdd.map(x => x._2).filter(x => reg.pattern.matcher(x).matches)
```

I create the .jar using sbt and running with spark-submit.

BTW, using spark-shell it works :S

I need your help please. Thanks.

Comment: I tested in Spark-Shell using a txt containing all the same data newAPIHadoopFile returned... but using it this way, it doeswork, even not in skarp-shell

Comment: Using this form in spark-shell I got this error: `val regexpr = """[a-zA-Z]+""".r
val separated = yy.map(line => regexpr.findAllIn(line).toList)` Error I got: `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Comment: I do it in certain way... `val filtrado = col3.filter(x => x.matches("[\\n\\s\\W\\w]+<title>([A-Za-z]+)</title>[\\n\\w\\s\\W]+"))` but... it retorned the whole page section and not only what I need

Comment: Ok... I got tire of that s... so... finally, I decided to use substring and indexof and it worked... no more regex for me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use built-in Scala support for XML. Something like

> import scala.xml._
>   rdd.map(x => (XML.loadString(x._2) \ "title").text)